# Xamarin : WCF Service and Integrated Windows Authentication

Tags: android, windows, wcf, authentication, xamarin

I have an ASP.net application that hosts a WCF service and uses Integrated Windows Authentication, I am trying to consume this service in Xamarin Android application.

**Application authentication settings in the IIS is configured as below.**
[image]

**Web.config at the service side defines service settings as below**

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="HttpWindowsBinding"
                 maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <services>
      <service name="EmployeeServicesWCF">
        <endpoint address="http://localhost:801/CSE/EmpServices/EmployeeServicesWCF.svc"
                  binding="HttpWindowsBinding"
                  contract="CivilServicesEmpProj.IEmployeeServicesWCF" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
```

**At the client side (Xamarin Android application) things arranged as follows**

After generating proxy class using SvcUtil.exe and adding the class to the project, I use the following code to consume the service.

```
     BasicHttpBinding binding = new BasicHttpBinding(BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly);
     binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Windows;

     EndpointAddress endpoint = new EndpointAddress("http://10.0.2.2:801/CSE/EmpServices/EmployeeServicesWCF.svc"); 

     EmployeeServicesWCFClient client = new EmployeeServicesWCFClient(binding, endpoint);
     client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "10.0.2.2\\MyUser";
     client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "mypass";


     Employee emp = client.GetEmployeeInfo();
```

When I run the code, I get this exception "System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object" at the only single line existing in the GetEmployeeInfo() method definition in the EmployeeDataServicesWCFClient class, please see below

```
public CSEDataContracts.Employee GetEmployeeInfo()
{
    return base.Channel.GetEmployeeInfo(user);
}
```

It worth mentioning that when I change authentication credentials in the above code to wrong credentials I get this exception instead "System.Net.WebException: There was an error on processing web request: Status code 401(Unauthorized): Unauthorized"

Any idea what could be the problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Xamarin : Authenticating Android application using Windows Authentication](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27239389/xamarin-authenticating-android-application-using-windows-authentication)

Comment: You already asked this and received several responses.  Have you read them?

Comment: yes I did, unfortunately answers were not accurate enough, both claims there is no direct way to do it, and as you can see from my code above it can be achieved in a pretty straight forward way it just need some tuning.